# How to solve the differential equation when a variable used in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp is the solution of another differential equation?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'd like to solve the differential equation defined as

```py
def eqn1(t, y):
    dydt = (A + B @ u) @ y
    return dydt
y = solve_ivp(eqn1, (t0, tf), y0, method='LSODA', t_eval=np.linspace(0, tf, 1000)) # this will not work cause u is unkonwn
```

where `A` and `B` are known constant matrice, but the variable `u` is the solution of another equation solved as

```py
def eqn2(t, u):
    dudt = Omega + u @ S @ u
    return dudt
```

and `u` should be gotten by

```py
u = solve_ivp(eqn2, (t0, tf), u0, method='LSODA', t_eval=np.linspace(0, tf, 1000))
```

`u` could be easily solved since the variables in `eqn2` are all known but **how can I get `y` by solve the `eqn1`**?

I have tried to call `solve_ivp` of `eqn2` to get `u` once `eqn1` is called:

```py
def eqn2(t, u):
    dudt = Omega + u @ S @ u
    return dudt

def eqn1(t, y):
    t_eval = np.linspace(0, tf, 1000)
    u = solve_ivp(eqn2, (t0, tf), u0, method='LSODA', t_eval=np.sort(np.append(t_eval, t)))
    u = u.y[np.where(u.t == t)[0][0]]
    dydt = (A + B @ u) @ x
    return dydt
y = solve_ivp(eqn1, (t0, tf), y0, method='LSODA', t_eval=np.linspace(0, tf, 1000))
```

but it is too slow and output a lot of warnings.

Comment: Is the `x` in `eqn1` supposed to be `y`? Also, can you share values for `A`, `B`, `Omega`, `S`, `t0`, `tf`, `y0`, and `u0`?

Comment: @jared The original values from my own code are too complex. For this problem, maybe you could set `t0=0`,'tf=10`,'A=np.zeros((10, 10))`, `B=np.eye(10)', `Omega=2 * np.eye(10)`, `S=4 * np.eye(10)`, `u0=np.random.randn(10)`

Comment: This should be added as an edit to your question. And make sure to include `y0`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a coupled system of DE, you can solve it as such

```
def ode_sys(t,y)
    x,u = np.reshape(y,[2,-1])
    dxdt = (A + B @ u) @ x
    dudt = Omega + u @ S @ u
    return np.concatenate([dxdt,dudt])
```

The other variant is to solve the `u` equation for a "dense output" solution and then use this interpolation function in the `y` equation to get the specific value `u = res_u.sol(t)`.

Comment: The dense solution was what I was going to suggest, if OP responded to my comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are calling `solve_ivp` twice for the same variable `u`. This is inefficient and can also lead to errors.

A better way to do this is to use a wrapper function. A wrapper function is a function that calls another function and then returns the results. In this case, you can create a wrapper function that calls `solve_ivp` for `eqn2` and then returns the solution.

The following code shows how to do this:

```
    def wrapper(t, y):
        u = solve_ivp(eqn2, (t0, tf), u0, method='LSODA', t_eval=np.sort(np.append(t_eval, t)))
        u = u.y[np.where(u.t == t)[0][0]]
        dydt = (A + B @ u) @ x
        return dydt

y = solve_ivp(wrapper, (t0, tf), y0, method='LSODA', t_eval=np.linspace(0, tf, 1000))
```

This code works by first calling `solve_ivp` for `eqn2` with the current time `t` and the initial condition `u0`. The results of this call are stored in the variable `u`. The value of `u` at time `t` is then extracted from `u` and used to compute the derivative `dydt`. Finally, the wrapper function returns `dydt`.

This code is more efficient than your original code because it only calls `solve_ivp` once for each value of `t`. It is also less likely to cause errors because the value of u is only computed once for each value of `t`.